# How to create multiple objects from array's value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dictionary

I have an array like this:

```
const data = [{
  color:"red",
  to:1,
  from:2,
  opacity:12
}]
```

I want something like this:

```js
const converted = [{from:2}, {to:1}, {opacity:12}]
```

What I am trying is:

```js
const mappedData = data.map(({from,to,opacity}) => ({from:from},{to:to},{opacity:opacity}))
```

but this is not working.

Comment: You can only return a single value from a function, so you would need to return an array `({from,to,opacity}) => [{from:from},{to:to},{opacity:opacity}])`. To create a flat array from the result use [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can loop through the array and for each object we can get the keys of the objects in the array and use a `map` to transform them to our desired output, Then the output will return an array, but we can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which will flatten the arrays returned into a single array of objects!

Thanks pilchard for teaching about flatMap!

```js
const data = [{
color:"red",
to:1,
from:2,
opacity:12

}]

const arr = data.flatMap(x => Object.keys(x).map(data => ({[data]: x[data]})))

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: just use `flatMap`. And don't just post code, take the time to explain what wasn't working about the OP's code.

Comment: @pilchard Thanks flat map is awesome, first I post then I edit it